# I can't center a pgf table or make it smaller because some data is hidden

Tags: pgfplotstable

I need to center or make a table smaller because some of its data is hidden out of the page.

I am using this pakages:

```
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

And this data:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tabel_2.dat}
X   B
0.5 35.42
1   35.45
1.5 35.50
2   35.47
2.5 35.40
3   35.48
5.5 35.49
4   35.44
4.5 35.42
5   35.42
5.5 35.41
6   35.39
6.4 35.39
7   35.48
7.5 35.47
8   35.50
8.5 35.51
9   35.49
\end{filecontents*}
```

And the code of the table is this:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/index/.style={%
    create col/assign/.code={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\entry{\pgfplotstablerow+1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}
    }
    }
    }
\pgfplotstabletranspose\loadedtable{tabel_2.dat} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={%
                           before row={\hline%
                           \multicolumn{19}{|c|}{Table data}
                           \\ },
                           output empty row},
    after row={\hline},
    every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},
    every column/.style={column type/.add={|}{}},
    string type]
{\loadedtable}
```

I cave tried \centering and other things but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it is just to ad `\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` in front.
Like this

````
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/index/.style={%
    create col/assign/.code={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\entry{\pgfplotstablerow+1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}
    }
    }
    }
\pgfplotstabletranspose\loadedtable{tabel_2.dat} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={%
                           before row={\hline%
                           \multicolumn{19}{|c|}{Table data}
                           \\ },
                           output empty row},
    after row={\hline},
    every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},
    every column/.style={column type/.add={|}{}},
    string type]
{\loadedtable}```
````